# Is there any option to create a single frame thumbnail for a video in java?

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, xuggler, jave

Is there any option to create a single frame thumbnail for a video in java with java libraries.

I am using Jave2 in my application. Does Jave2 provides any such options? I didn't find a single documentation related to this.

I heard Xuggler provides some options. But I don't want to move to Xuggler if Jave2 provides the facility as I'm already using Jave2 for many purposes extensively. Adding a full library like Xuggler is an overhead. Replacing Jave2 with Xuggler also is a tedious task

If any light weight thumbnail feature specific utility library is available, then that should also be fine.

Comment: For now I solved my issue with front javascript to get the thumbnail for me and pass it to backend.